# Passing a service dependency injection for controller testing

Tags: angularjs

`AllData.js` contains the following code

```
    var module = angular.module("myApp", []);

    module.service("StoreService", function () {

    this.AddCategory = function (newCategoryToAdd) {
            var categoriesLocal = [];
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Category/Create",
                type: "POST",
                data: "{'newCategoryToAdd' : '" + newCategoryToAdd + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                error: function (xhr) {
                    alert('Error: ' + xhr.statusText);
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    categoriesLocal = result;
                },
                async: false

            });
            return categoriesLocal;
        }
    }
module.controller("CategoryController", function ($scope, StoreService) {
});
```

`CategoryControllerFile` contains the test code :

```
/// <reference path="C:\Programming\New Projects\MVCAngular1App\MVCAngular1App\Scripts/jasmine/jasmine.js" />
/// <reference path="C:\Programming\New Projects\MVCAngular1App\MVCAngular1App\Scripts/angular-mocks.js" />
/// <reference path="C:\Programming\New Projects\MVCAngular1App\MVCAngular1App\Scripts/angular.min.js" />
/// <reference path="C:\Programming\New Projects\MVCAngular1App\MVCAngular1App\Scripts/AllData.js" />

decribe('CategoryControllerTest', function () {
    beforeEach(module('myApp'));
    var $controller, StoreService;

    beforeEach(inject(function (_CategoryController_, _StoreService_) {

        $controller = _CategoryController_;
        StoreService = _StoreService_;

    }));
    describe('$scope.AddCategory', function () {
        it('adds a category', function () {
            var $scope = {};
            var controller = $controller('CategoryController', { $scope: $scope });
            var length = $scope.categories.length;
            $scope.newCategory = "TestCategory";
            $scope.AddCategory($scope.newCategory);
            var newLength = $scope.categories.length;
            expect($scope.categories.length).toEqual(newLength);
        });
    });
});
```

How to inject my service as dependency injection in my test method

I have edited my code to show from respective files

Comment: NEVER use `async: false` for ajax requests. It is a terrible practice and is deprecated by browser vendors. You should be seeing warning messages in browser console. Use promise callbacks.

Comment: Where does your service method `AddCategory` get bound to your controller scope?  Shouldn't you have a line in your controller like `$scope.AddCategory = StoreService.AddCategory`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
describe('CategoryControllerTests', function () {
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('myAppTest'));        
    describe('sets the controller', function () {
        var controller, scope, StoreService2;

        beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, _StoreService_) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            StoreService2 = _StoreService_
            controller = $controller('CategoryController', { $scope: scope, StoreService: StoreService2 });            
        }));
        it("categories length property", function () {            
            var categories = scope.categories;
            expect(categories.length).toEqual(2);                        
        });
    });
});



var module = angular.module("myAppTest", []).service("StoreService", ["$http", function ($http) {
    this.GetAllCategories = function () {
        var categoriesLocal = [];
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:58641/Category/GetAllCategories/",
            type: "GET",
            data: "{}",
            dataType: 'json',
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(xhr.responseText);
                alert(thrownError);
            },
            success: function (result) {
                categoriesLocal = result;
            },
            async: false
        });
        return categoriesLocal;
    }
}]).controller("CategoryController", ["$scope", "StoreService", function ($scope, StoreService) {
    $scope.categories = StoreService.GetAllCategories();
}]);
```

Finally it works! This is the correct code.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would inject a service:

```
decribe('CategoryControllerTests', function(){
    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    var $controller, StoreService ;

    beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_, _StoreService_) {

        $controller = _$controller_;
        StoreService = _StoreService_;

    }));
};
```

Comment: Nope. It does not work. I am still getting test failed. Message: Error: [$injector:modulerr]?

Comment: First things first: I'm assuming the code you posted in the question is copied from various files. Can you show what you actually have in each file? Also, do you have a beforeEach(module('myApp')); (Edited my answer to show this)

Comment: Also, the  Error: [$injector:modulerr] ususally comes with a hyperlink which if you follow gives you a more detailed explanation of what it can't find.

Comment: OK, well looks like you're missing "beforeEach(module('myApp'));"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104790/discussion-between-andyhasit-and-sly-chandan).

Comment: I have fixed some issues and now I have the Message: Error: [$injector:unpr] and i have followed all the actions mentioned in the link...but nothing helps

Comment: See more suggestions in chat.